Verifier running polynomial commitment
Context : SNARK and zero knowledge, and here polynomial commitment
Spartan: Efficient and general-purpose zkSNARKs
without trusted setup (7.2.2)

the Spartan verifier runs the
Commit algorithm (of the sparse polynomial commitment scheme) as part of the Encode
algorithm, so unlike the general setup of polynomial commitments, the entity creating
a commitment is the verifier itself (not an untrusted entity).

My thoughts :
I see how it is possible to consider a polynomial commitment scheme with some kind of third party or trusted setup, I am confused by having the verifier to run the commitment.
Question(s) :
Is this a classic consideration to make (commit algorithm run by V) ? In which context can we say this ?

Here to explain what I have understood of this paper. In the context of R1CS-based SNARK, they tranform R1CS IOP into a polynomial IOP.
In a preprocessing step, the verifier commit three polynomials (assumed to represent the R1CS instance). However, the "binding" property of the commitment is not useful. It is something like a compression of the polynomials into a C helpful to verify some evaluations.
